# Is it possible to share data across multiple accounts?

Tags: nexus-7, restricted-profiles

I have a 2012 Nexus 7 with stock Android. I have the owner account and have created a restricted account for my kids.
For each account it creates a separate space for each users data.

However I would like to share movies, music and other data between the accounts. Is this possible?

Comment: Not having a multi-user capable device I cannot verify it, but shouldn't that work via space on the (external) SDCard? Usually everything there is "world readable/writeable".

Comment: Thanks Izzy. I think this would work but Nexus 7 doesn't have an external SD.

Comment: Right. Have you tried via the internal one? IMHO it should behave similar, being treaded as "SDCard" as well.

Comment: /sdcard is realy folder, every user have it's own folder without sharing :(